# Use FirebaseUI with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, firebaseui

I haven't found any samples. Is it possible to use the [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) with AngularFire2? AFAIK the UI is not part of AngularFire2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is indeed no direct integration between FirebaseUI (for the web) and AngularFire2.

AngularFire2 has built in sign-in primitives that integrate with the lower-level sign-in functionality of the Firebase Authentication JavaScript SDK. For more about those, see the [AngularFire2 documentation on user authentication](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md).

But given that both AngularFire2 and FirebaseUI-Web are built on top of the Firebase Authentication JavaScript SDK, they'll likely work together fine too. If you [start a sign-in flow from FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#starting-the-sign-in-flow), it will in the end [trigger an `onAuthStateChanged()` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) on the SDK level. That is the [same event that AngularFire2 listens to](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/f875360f4eb8213d5cdb9924b2212ad647b4b1ea/src/auth/firebase_sdk_auth_backend.ts#L53) to fire its own `onAuth()` event.

Comment: A real working example of this would be really nice. There is https://github.com/RaphaelJenni/FirebaseUIAngularIntegration but it's not working for me. `FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

Comment: Seems like a duplicate call to `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` is required in addition to calling `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` in `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, AngularFire and FirebaseUI can work together. You need to:

1: Import FirebaseUI and give it access to firebase (e.g. before bootstrap)

```typescript
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

// Attach firebase to window so FirebaseUI can access it
(<any>window).firebase = firebase

// Import FirebaseUI standalone (as its npm.js file causes double firebase code)
import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui'  // Imports for side effects only

// Declare `window.firebaseui` that the above import creates
declare global {
    const firebaseui
}
```

[Why you can't just `import * as firebaseui` like you do with firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/198#issuecomment-319819592)

2: Init FirebaseUI in a service (so that it only happens once), and pass it the auth instance created by AngularFire.

```typescript
constructor(private af_auth: AngularFireAuth){
    this.fui_auth = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.af_auth.auth)
}
```

3: Render the UI in a component

```typescript
@Component({
    'selector': 'app-signin',
    'template': '',  // Populated by `fui_auth.start()`
})
export class SigninComp {

    constructor(private user: UserService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        // Show Firebase UI auth widget
        this.user.fui_auth.start('app-signin', {config...}})
    }
}
```

There is also [a module available](https://github.com/RaphaelJenni/FirebaseUI-Angular) but it currently suffers from [this issue](https://github.com/RaphaelJenni/FirebaseUI-Angular/issues/16)